# GCP Instance: Ipython Notebook Download to local system

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning

Hi I want to download my ipython notebook which I created using the Ubuntu machine 
on GCP?
Can anyone suggest any method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to download your `.ipynb` files. Follow the following steps:
Go to `File` -> `Download as` -> select the format you want the download.

If this doesn't answer your question kindly let me know.